# Search and delete vba code needs optimizing

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets (ProductList and CurrentProducts)

I have the following code :

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim BinNo As String
Dim MyCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Lastrow = Sheets("ProductsList").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For x = Lastrow To 2 Step -1

BinNo = Sheets("ProductsList").Range("A" & x).Value

With Sheets("CurrentProducts").Range("A:A")
    Set MyCell = .Find(What:=BinNo, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

    If Not MyCell Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("CurrentProducts").Range(MyCell.Address).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
 End With

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

What this does is take each value from column A in ProductList, searches for it in CurrentProducts and if it finds the value then deletes the entire row from CurrentProducts so I am left with any new products in the CurrentProducts sheet.

This code works but is very slow and takes about 5 minutes to run.

Each sheet has about 30,000 rows.

Is there a way to speed this up or is it just because there are so many rows?

Comment: If the code works, and you need optimizing/review, then you should post it in **Code Review** section, at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to CodeReview as stipulated here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review Reason: the code is working and the OP himself / herself asks for a way to improve upon the performance of the working code. There is no bug or error to overcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this can be done a lot quicker through the use of a formula. For instance you could do a vlookup. You could then sort the sheet and delete any rows that returned a value.

This is one possible solution.

There are many similar things I can think of. But using a formula would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("ProductsList")
Set ws2 = Sheets("CurrentProducts")

With ws2
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Columns(1).Insert
    .Range("A2:A" & lr).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & ws1.Name & "!A:A,B2),NA(),"""")"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
    .Columns(1).Delete
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```